# JS STORE Delete based on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a [jsstore](https://jsstore.net/) table with the following schma

```
const loiCommonNameSchema = {
    name: 'LOICommonName',
    columns: {
        projectId: { dataType: 'string', index: true },
        Uniclass2_Id: { dataType: 'string' },
        commonName: { dataType: 'string', allowNull: true },
        code: { dataType: 'string', allowNull: true },
        cacheKey: { dataType: 'string',  index: true },
    },
};
```

I'm trying to run a delete operation on this table in the following way

```
            var dae =  await connection.remove({
                from:  'LOICommonName',
                where: {
                    projectId: projectId,
                    cacheKey: { '!=': 'hello' }
                },
                ignoreCase: true
            });
```

this is return
store.worker.min.js:2 {message: "No index found for column 'undefined'. Query can not be executed without index.", type: 'no_index_found'}

I've tried to run a delete on just the projectId and this works
I've also tried to run a delete on just the cacheKey and the works as expected.

I ran a select with the Where and this returned the set of data that I would expect to get deleted.

I'm not sure what I need to change in my schema to allow for a delete with a complex WHERE statement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks ahead of time.

Comment: https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/discussions/320 I've also added a discussion to the jsstore. repo